# Variable in try catch exception

Tags: c#, try-catch

Whats the differenc of using a variable inside the try section and the catch section

```
string curNamespace;

try
{
  curNamespace = "name"; // Works fine
}
catch (Exception e)
{
// Shows use of unassigned local variable  
throw new Exception("Error reading " + curNamespace, e);

}
```

If i use variable inside try section it compiles fine, in catch section i get "Use of unassigned variable"

Comment: **Use of unassigned variable** is a warning which you can ignore if you choose.  Otherwise the problem is perfectly clear.  You do not assign a value before you attempt to use **curNamespace** so set a value.  I would actually suggest String.Empty instead of setting it to **null**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The compiler is complaining because you may encounter an exception **before** the value is initialized. Consider the following (very contrived) example:

```
string curNamespace;
try {
    throw new Exception("whoops");

    curNamespace = "name"; // never reaches this line
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // now curNamespace hasn't been assigned!
    throw new Exception("Error reading " + curNamespace, e);

}
```

The fix would be to initialize `curNamespace` to some default value outside the `try..catch`. Have to wonder what you're trying to use it for, though.

Comment: He said '*it compiles fine*' though, so it's not the compiler that's complaining as you say.

Comment: @Diego Try it in your environment. With VS 2010 & .NET 4 the compiler definitely does not allow this by default. I suppose it's possible to change that to a warning - and maybe the OP has.

Comment: @Yuck - This answer is both "correct" and "incorrect"  The reason the compiler is complaining is because the variable has not been assigned a value before its used.  But based on the code provided it was intialized ( just withing being assigned a value ).

Comment: @Yuck - The code will compile using .NET 4, adjust your warning settings, because the default settings would allow this.

Comment: @Diego, he says "it compiles fine **if he uses it in the try section.**" But then he goes on to report a compiler error. Do the inference, he's tried it without the catch usage, and now with. It's the catch usage that is causing the compiler to complain.

Comment: @Ramhound, to my knowledge, there is no way to set a compiler warning level to ignore something that is *illegal* per the language specification. I would question whether you are compiling this code *exactly.*

Answer (score 3):

It means that variable `curNamespace` was not initialized before using it in `catch` scope.

Change your code to this:

```
string curNamespace = null;
```

And it will compile fine.

In **C#**, variables must be initialized before being used. So this is wrong:

```
string curNamespace; // variable was not initialized
throw new Exception("Error reading " + curNamespace); // can't use curNamespace because it's not initialized
```

Comment: That's not true Pablo. `curNamespace` was defined outside the try-catch block, therefore it's accessible inside try catch.

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted, it is correct. The compiler cannot definitively prove the variable has been assigned prior to being used in the `catch`.

Comment: @Diego, being *defined* and being *definitively assigned* are two different things. Pablo's answer says nothing about defining.

Comment: @Diego: did not read the whole question before answering. Now it's been corrected. Thanks!

Comment: I have no reason this was given a negative vote. This is the correct answer. There isn't a reason to go into more detail because this is part of the C# standard.  The original answer was acceptable.  I don't understand the complaint.

Answer (score 3):

You have to assign it outside the try block.

```
        string curNamespace = string.Empty; // or whatever

        try
        {
            curNamespace = "name";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error reading " + curNamespace, e);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize curNamespace first. Or it "could" be uninitialized in the catch branch.

Comment: Based on the author's example code there is no way it could not be initialized ( this clearly happen).  It just was never assigned a value before being used.  This is only a warning and in the case of the example code could be ignored.

Comment: @Ramhound, you appear to be using "initialized" to mean "defined." That's not the correct usage. Initialization is essentially assignment, as far as this usage goes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign something to the variable because it is not guaranteed that the variable will hold something when it's used.

You can do with:

string curNamespace = String.Empty;

Answer (score 0):

If you change your declaration of `curNamespace` and assign something to it, it will work:

```
string curNamespace = null; /* ASSIGN SOMETHING HERE */
try
{
  curNamespace = "name";
}
catch (Exception e)
{
throw new Exception("Error reading " + curNamespace, e);

}
```